# How does Python come off as a multi-platform programming language?

Tags: python, user-interface, cross-platform

I'm talking about deploying Python-made, GUI-based, desktop applications via .app and .exe format for OSX and Windows. As far as I've gone into Python, I've only seen it as an application that runs on the Terminal / Command Prompt. I know that it is possible to create a user interface for it using various offerings on the internet (wxPython?). I just want to see how it passess off as a way for a developer to create mac and windows applications with as little code difference as possible.

Comment: Not really a comprehensive answer, but I think that if you used cross-platform GUI framework (e.g. Qt) then you should only have to concern yourself with OS-specific python code. I mean packages like "subprocess" or "os" which sometimes behave a bit differently depending on the platform. Other than that I'd say it should be pretty hassle-free with tools like Py2App or Py2Exe. I haven't tested or done that, so it's just a loose thought and I might not be 100% right.

Answer (score 1):

I find that Python is a very good language for GUI programming. As you have stated, you can use the bindings for wxWidgets (wxPython), but there's also a binding for just about every other cross-platform GUI toolkit you can think of (Tk, Qt, GTK, FLTK, etc.). These GUI toolkits should allow you to make a program that will run unmodified on most OSs.

In terms of Python OS compatibility, it will behave virtually the same on all OSs, except for one or two modules such as `mmap`.

Using py2exe, py2app, or similar tools, you can embed a Python interpreter (along with your program's bytecode and it's dependencies) within an executable, making it easy to distribute an application. An end user can then open the program as they are used to. If you want the "security" of a compiled language, Python will not be the best language for you to use (but I prefer readability over safety :).

Another thing to consider with cross-platformness is what OS specific features you plan on using. Most GUI toolkits will not support things such as Microsoft's DWM (though you can use OS features through `ctypes`).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [PyQT](http://www.diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/StartPage) and [Tkinter](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter).  Both are GUI Libraries for use with Python.  Both are cross-platform.  Further, for packaging up .exe and .app for distribution, look at [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) and [py2app](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, the easiest approach is [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/).  There's also a similar project for MacOS.  It's called [py2app](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html).  Most GUI frameworks are cross platform.  Just check their documentation, or even the home pages should have it.

Make good use of the `os` module.  It has many function that will handle cross platform situations.  A common example is file paths.  When you build a path should it be backslash or forward slash?  `os.path.join` handles that for you, and works based on which operating system it's running on.  You shouldn't have to modify your code at all when shipping from OS to OS.  It should run on Linux just as well, naturally.

By the way, MacOS often comes prepackaged with Python.  As long as it's a somewhat recent version this can make the difference between a Hello World script being 1kb and 30mb, so avoid packaging Python with it.  Unfortunately Windows isn't as well equip.  Consider an option for "I already have Python installed" when downloading the exe.